# win32 Python - pythoncom error - ImportError: No module named pywintypes

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, importerror, pythoncom

I am trying to import pythoncom, but it gives me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Documents and Settings/Emery/Desktop/Python 27/Try", line 2, in 
    import pythoncom
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in 
    import pywintypes
ImportError: No module named pywintypes

I reinstalled Python win32, but it still doesn't fix it. Any help? Also, I am trying to access the pythoncom.PumpMessages() method, an alternative would be nice as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an IDE like I am (PyCharm), you should go the where the Python is installed e.g `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`

In this folder check for the folder name `pywin32`. Copy that folder and paste it to `C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\project\venv\Lib\site-packages`. After that restart your IDE, then it will import the `pywin32` as it did in my case. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

pip install --upgrade pywin32==228