# No pumpmessages on PythonCom

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to build a keylogger :

```
import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui
import pythoncom, pyHook
import os
```

```
    hm = pyHook.HookManager() 
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent 
    # set the hook 
    hm.HookKeyboard() 
    # wait forever 
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

But i have a problem,
It says that my "Module 'pythoncom' has no 'PumpMessages' member"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [win32 Python - pythoncom error - ImportError: No module named pywintypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536952/win32-python-pythoncom-error-importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes)

Comment: Cant find that second folder, i only got 1 "site-packages"